# React UseEffect Updating State but no Rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an extremely simple issue in which I would like to load input devices and list them. [The Web API for Media Devices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) shows it returns a promise, so I assumed I would have to load this into the state with a useEffect hook.

React Developer tools shows a list of strings in the inputs array, although the state does not update.

```
const App = () => {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let inputDevices = [];
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
      devices.forEach((device) => inputDevices.push(device.label));
    });
    setInputs([inputDevices]);
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
      <ol>
        {inputs.map((device, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              id:{index} - Device: {device}{" "}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
```

output:

[image]

[image]

*edit: the setinputs([inputDevices]) was an accident, thank you all who reminded me about the asynchronicity of the promise :)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is `setInputs` will be execute before the `then` callback, so you need to `setInputs` inside the `then` callback, and you can use `map` to get the list of `labels`.

```js
    let inputDevices = [];
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
      setInputs(devices.map((device) => device.label))
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  let inputDevices = [];
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
      devices.forEach((device) => inputDevices.push(device.label));
    });
    setInputs([inputDevices]);
```

You need to call set state inside `then`. Promises are resolved asynchronously hence when you call `setInputs` where you have it by that time data isn't there yet.

You can also just utilize `map`:

```
setInputs(devices.map((device) => device.label)) // inside .then
```